# Dataflow job writing duplicate records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I have an Apache Beam job run on Dataflow. It reads from some avro files, redacts data in specified columns and writes back out to avro files in Cloud Storage.

```
    read_from_avro \
        | 'Group into batches' >> beam.BatchElements(700) \
        | "RedactData" >> RedactPIIData(project, redact_fields) \
        | beam.FlatMap(lambda elements: elements)
```

The issue I'm having is that for very large datasets, we're getting duplicated rows written back out. In the case of about ~30M rows, we find there are between 10-40k extra rows, all duplications.

(FYI in the code above the data is batched to keep us under the GCP DLP API request limit)

I have no idea why this would be. In the dataflow metrics UI, I can see the expected number of elements added at each stage. The elements in the ReadFromAvro stage == elements in the WriteToAvro stage. In doing some research I understand that it is possible that the data is duplicated as the job autoscales and more workers are added, yet I thought that Dataflow processed data 'exactly once'.

Just to add, adding a `beam.Reshuffle()` does rectify this issue however as it's experimental at this stage it cannot be added.

I also implemented a UUID on each record and did a GroupByKey at the end of the pipeline before the WriteToAvro, which worked locally, but this does not work on the DataflowRunner.

Comment: Regarding the exactly once semantics used in dataflow, you may find this article, https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-cloud-dataflow-part-3-sources-and-sinks, especially the "Exactly once in sinks" section, helpful; and why adding a reshuffle could help.

Comment: Thanks @AndyXu, what is your opinion on it being noted as experimental (using python)? I see it's been around for a few years, any reason why it's not in full use?

Comment: Not sure about the story behind the experimental annotate. However, I noticed it is used in beam SDK core code itself, e.g., https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L2958. Therefore I would expect it won't go away suddenly :)